# Does the diameter of the coil in a motor determine the amount of volts needed to run it?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, motor, dc, coil

I am making a DC motor and i got coil from a transformer and the coil is a lot thicker than the coil in your usual DC motor, i want to ensure that the motor runs on 9 volts, the coil is about 1 mm in diameter.

[image]

So my question is:

***Will it run on more than 9 volts?***

Comment: If the wire gauge is not the same then you can get as many turns, then you cant drive it with as much voltage and then it wont run as fast.

Comment: ah "coil diameter" is supposed to mean "wire gauge"? I thought you actually meant the diameter of the *windings*...

Comment: This is like saying: I built an internal combustion engine, what kind of fuel should I run on it? Motor design is a complex topic, and an answer would be several pages. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the diameter of the coil in a motor determine the amount of volts needed to run it?

No. It's a mechanical design consideration; indirectly, it does affect field strength, but that only indirectly links with voltage...

So, Motor design is a complex topic full of tradeoffs.

There's literally dozens of different kinds of eletrical motor designs, and every one of them has a different relation between coil diameter, wire resistance/diameter, coil currents, forces and moments, speed and voltages.

I'm afraid you'll have to dig through a bit of literature on your specific motor type if you need info on how to build a motor to operate at a certain voltage giving you certain operational characteristics (current, torque, speed, reluctance, temperature…).